# What's the purpose of "functions" if they can be replaced by "tasks" in Verilog HDL?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, hdl

In Verilog, a `task` can do everything that a `function` can along with having other features. Then what's the purpose of having functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statements are not correct. A `task` can only be used as a statement, whereas a `function` may return a value and be used as part of an expression. A function with a `void` return type is like a task, but is guaranteed not to consume time. So a task may call another task or function, but a function can only call other functions.

Comment: But a `task` can also sort of return one or more values with the help of `output` keyword, right? So whether we create a `function` `sum` and use it as `c = sum(a,b)` or declare an `output` port inside a `task` and use it as `sum(a,b,c)` - does it make any difference apart from the mapping?

Comment: If you need two different functions in one expression, you would have to create two intermediate variables to hold the result of each output.

There are many places outside of procedural code that you may want to use a function and cannot use a task(a continuous assignment, an assertion). But tes there are ways to code without it, just as there are ways to code without using tasks. It depends on how difficult you want to make your code readable and maintainable.

Comment: The way I think of it is:  functions are for combinatorial logic, and tasks are for sequential.  Of course, I use functions inside sequential blocks, but the function itself generates a bunch of comb. logic.  

Sometimes, I use always blocks to generate comb logic too.  always @(*).   Usually, this is so I can use a case statement.  You could also use a task inside one of these. 

As @Killjoy pointed out, there are multiple ways to code anything.  Everyone will have their own style.  Verilog tasks and functions provide some tools to simplify your code.